# Upload a file to multiple servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I see a ton of questions about uploading multiple files, but none about uploading a single file to multiple servers, so here goes...

I have an ASP.NET app that will be running on two load balanced servers, and I would like to allow users to upload files and have them end up on both servers. What is the cleanest way to do this? I am using IIS 6 btw.

Some ideas that come to mind are:

1) Use a virtual directory that points to some shared location that both servers can access. Will there be any access issues if the application runs at Network Service? I'm assuming the application will need to run as a user account that exists on the shared location machine. How should the permissions be set for this?

2) It would be nice if I could via jQuery post the request to both of my servers, referencing them by their port numbers. Even though the servers are on the same domain, this violates the same origin policy, right?

Is there another solution I'm overlooking? How do other sites do this?

Comment: what did you end up doing? I'm looking for a solution for this.

Comment: I honestly don't remember what project I was working on at the time of posting, so I'm not sure what I ended up doing for this. At some point, I ended up using the fact that these multiple web servers happened to talk to a single SQL Server instance, so I stuffed some files in the database, lololol. Your milage may vary and that could very well be a terrible idea.

Comment: oh yes it is terrible idea.lol..we store in project directory. planning to move that website on azure and ha environment now, so tasked with changing files the way we store. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to consider this problem more carefully - having a pair (or more) of servers means that some of them will be offline some of the time (at least for occasional reboots).

Uploads when not all of the servers are online won't be able to be sent to all servers immediately, so you'd need either an intermediate server (which would be a point of failure unless it was highly available itself) or a queuing system to "remember" which files were where, and to transfer them when the relevant servers were restored.

Also, you'll want a backup system, and some way to add newly provisioned servers to your cluster. You will also want a way to monitor these files are the same in case they get out of sync. Your architecture needs a lot of careful thought. I don't have the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest approach is forwarding the files server-side, really. If you force two uploads via JavaScript, not only will you have to worry about working around XSS safeguards, but you'll also force the user to use their very limited upstream bandwidth twice for each file.

You shouldn't be exposing that kind of detail to the client anyway. The browser doesn't need to know where the file ends up, just who to send it to. If you keep that logic server-side, not only do you keep the details hidden (and thus less prone to errors and exploits), but you'll also get more control over the process. You can create a gateway service later that handles a multitude of back end storages and you can handle failing servers better. You can queue failed uploads and retry. All these come at a very low cost if you do them on the server side, but are a pain to be made to work reliably on the client side.

Keep back end logic to your back end. Load balancing should be hidden from the user, so there's no need to tell them where they are sending their files exactly. Make it optional, if you want, but hide the action from them. Just swallow the file on the gateway server (which can be either of the load balancing servers -- in fact, it should probably be load balanced, too, so it should work with either of them in place) and send it to the other servers from there. The transfer from server to server will probably be faster too.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is definitely a NAS, if one is available -- a shared file system that is not specifically associated with any machine.  Then you can focus on making the NAS highly available via a clustered frontend.

If that's not an option, you can use a virtual directory on each machine that points to one folder on one of the machines, but then you lose redundancy.

I'm faced with this same challenge at my work.  My app is small but needs to be highly available, but there's no NAS in sight. So in each machine's web.config I place a list of all the UNC paths that the uploaded file should be stored.  After uploading to a temp folder, I copy the file to each machine one by one.  It's not perfect -- a machine could go down, in which case when it came up it might not have all the files (and the copy would be slowed by the hunt for the missing machine) -- but in my situation uploads are so infrequent that it's not worth improvement.

As others have mentioned, Javascript is right out.  Upload once.

Comment: How do you have permissions set so your app write to each machine? Does your app run as Network Service or does it impersonate an ID that has access an each machine?

Comment: They do impersonation for the file copy.  We have a domain account, but if two servers have the exact same username/password available you can use that interchangeably as well.  You may want to encrypt the password in your config file.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem solved with a NAS, using credentials for the app pool that can read/write files to that NAS.  Make sure your NAS is setup for high availability to prevent single point of failure ie:hot swap w/ raid, multiple array controllers, power supplies..etc

You could also put folder monitoring software on the severs that keep certain directories in sync.  I don't recommend this solution.